# Programmatically creating paragraphs is extremely slow

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I am adding paragraphs from xml file programmatically but it is extremely slow. for example I'm basically creating paragraphs like this:

```
$row = ['field_title' => 'title', 'field_id' => 'id' ....];
$paragraph = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('paragraph')->create($row);
```

I have at least ten paragraphs for node and it is taking approximately 2-3 minutes to create for one paragraph.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Where do you write that code?

Comment: when importing data in drush commands php. It is creating paragraph but it is exteremely slow.

Comment: You don't need to save the newly created paragraph, new paragraphs get saved automatically when the parent entity is saved.

Comment: Yes you are right but it is still slow.

Comment: Have you tried running it on a better computer to make sure your hardware/software configuration isn't the problem?

Comment: Yes, I've tried still slow.

Comment: There must be more to the picture here because I do this a lot and it never takes more than a few seconds.